# Flexbox compatibility (emphasis on kindle fire)

Tags: css, flexbox, kindle-fire

So I have a question pertaining to flexbox support on Kindle devices, and if you have anymore information on overall support in general. It seems that the `display:flex` and `flex-wrap:wrap/nowrap` properties aren't supported, at least on the earlier kindle fire devices (I've read it is on the newer ones but have no way of testing). It looks as though `flex:box` (the older version of flexbox is supported however).

I've taken to using different display properties and then using the `@support (display:flex)` or `(flex-wrap:wrap)` to target devices that support flexbox in a progressively enhanced manner (if they support flexbox odds are they support media queries) so firefox has no issues on the wrap (also use the url-prefix for -moz-), and kindle fire has no issues overall, but am wondering if there is another solution out there? I mean this method nearly doubles the layout code.

[www.caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox) only states that opera-mini 5-7 and IE 8-9 lacks support, and has known issues for: (also displays vendor prefixes which I resolve with AutoPrefixer)

> Firefox does not support specifying widths in percentages.
>
> IE10 and IE11 default values for `flex` are `0 0 auto`
>   rather than `0 1 auto`, as per the draft spec, as of September 2013.
>
> Firefox does not support flex-wrap, align-content properties.
>
> In IE10 and IE11, containers with `display: flex` and `flex-direction:
>   column` will not properly calculate their flexed childrens' sizes if
>   the container has `min-height` but no explicit `height` property.

and has an article on cross-browser support: http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/advanced-cross-browser-flexbox/

But I have been unable to find anything relating to the kindle devices.

Comment: If Kindle only supports the original Flexbox draft (which you already know from your own testing), the problem is what exactly?

Comment: I guess I was hopeful that someone would say there was a new and "easy" method or polyfill that would resolve the added development time of making flexbox compatible and fully supported specifically with the `flex-wrap:wrap;` property. Unfortunately, as I suspected and as Wes pointed out, I must still use older methods with the new to achieve full support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sadly yes, it doubles and probably more the layout code, this is why imho you shouldn't use, for example, `flex-wrap` since it's available only on chrome21+, because it will carry you to create a totally different layout

support only the ~standard syntax, the MSIE10 syntax (which is very similar) and the -webkit- legacy syntax (for android 2.x support)

- `@supports` isn't widely available yet
- for feature detection i suggest modernizr; plus, on github there are various plugins for testing against specific flexbox properties/values, or you could write them yourself
- however kindle fire is android 2.3, then it more than likely uses Webkit 533, therefore  it supports the legacy flexbox `-webkit-` syntax
- `flex:box` never existed, but `(moz|webkit)box-flex:1` and `display:(moz|webkit)box`
- default values aren't a problem, just do `*{...}` to normalize them
- `flex-wrap:wrap` isn't widely supported (firefox 29, chrome 21, msie11) so you shouldn't use it... if you want something similar you may use the multi-column layout module for vertical flow or inline-block for horizontal flow. sadly at the moment this is the best choice
- percentages work on firefox (http://jsfiddle.net/RBaR2/)... the missing percentages support  bug refers to the old -moz-box syntax, that you shouldn't use (really really old firefox)

http://dundalek.com/css3-flexbox-reference/

http://zomigi.com/blog/flexbox-syntax-for-ie-10/

Comment: You sir are a champ. Thanks for the quick response. Flexbox just simplifies items so much I think I'm trying to will it to work as opposed to approaching this logically. I'm going to leave this as a +1 not a correct answer for a while to draw more attention and see what others have to say, but I appreciate your answer greatly and will probably mark it.

Comment: Modernizr incorrectly reports Firefox as supporting Flexbox thanks to DHolbert's efforts (see: https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/issues/744).

Comment: Thanks for that cimmanon. And I just noticed why you said `flex:box` never existed, I meant `display:box`, must have been a tad absent minded during write up.